# How to dynamically change the visibility of label in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code

```
<div> @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.WrongLogin) </div>
```

I want to display the label dynamically based on a condition from the server side code in the controller. If the controller returns `false` value then I need to make the label `visible`.

Comment: can you describe about the condition i.e it is coming from model or at client sode

Answer (score 6):

Just use an `if` statement:

```
@if (Model.LoginFailed) // Or whatever...
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WrongLogin);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet answer is correct, you can use ViewBag if you don't want Model.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.IsValid = false; //or true based on your condition

    return View();
}
```

**View Page**

```
@if (ViewBag.IsValid)
{
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.WrongLogin)</div>    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another one way in `Jquery`,

By default make the `Div Invisible` and set the div `Id`. Like Below,

**In .cshtml**

```
<div style="display:none" id="DivWrongLogin">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.WrongLogin) 
</div>
```

**In Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     if('@Model.LoginFailed' == false)
     {
         $('#DivWrongLogin').show();
     }
});
```